# How download a file from php using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, php

For example, if running this link in browser start to download a file named file.json (big file):

*http://localhost/extractor/download_file.php*

The download_file.php define some variables and call another php file (details.php). The details.php has "Content-Disposition: attachment" definition with the name of the file generated as results of the execution.

Because I need to schedule the download process, how execute this command from shell script?

Comment: Are you allowed to use cURL? That will allow you to download from the link as if you're using a web browser.

Comment: Yes, the details.php uses cURL and works perfectly from web browsers. Now I need to preparer a shell script to run automatically.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you should be able to just add `curl -o file.json http://localhost/extractor/download_file.php` to your crontab (or shell script, if you need to do other things with it)

Comment: I tried that. The file.json is created empty. I tried curl -JOL too and nothing happens.